# How to print array value ('value1', 'value2' ) in php for javascript

Tags: php, arrays

I have array with month and i need to print only values as 'Oct', 'Nov'

```
echo implode(', ', $months);
```

I tried implode but got the values as Oct, Nov I need these to be like 'Oct', 'Nov'

Any idea how can i go this?

Comment: You'll need to `foreach()` through the array and do this manually

Comment: foreach($months as $month) { echo "'".$month."', "; }

Comment: @Saleem You get an extra comma at the end

Comment: It worked Thank you and before i was trying this don't know why cannot get the results. this time it worked :)

Comment: @Saleem , you've get to erase the last comma , otherwise check my answer :)

Comment: why not using `json_encode` ? this looks to be the best solution to share information between php and javascript.

Answer (score 4):

The only proper way to do what you want is by using [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode).

```
echo json_encode($months);
```

*Any* solution that uses string functions, `implode`, etc. is likely to fail in edge cases. Unlikely to happen with just month names but it's still better to do it properly.

Comment: @Saleem: Did it work for you? In this case please consider accepting the answer (by clicking the gray checkmark icon on the left side)

Answer (score 0):

This is not very elegant but that will do the job:

```
echo '\''.implode('\', \'', $months). '\'';
```

Comment: Since when can you specify two `glue`s? This would be news to me.

Comment: I tested the code before posting it, needless to say.... http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: works if your array has a size > 0, but why not using `"'" . implode("', '", $months) . "'"` ? This looks clearer in a review isn't it? Is there a huge perf difference between single/double quotes?

Comment: If the array is size 0, you get an empty string '', it's up to you to see if that's what you want or not.
I don't know if the perf difference is huge or not, but to me it's always been part of my 'best practices' to put single quotes when double are not needed. Now that you say it I read here http://phpbench.com/ that in modern version of PHP there's no point of using single quotes.

Answer (score -1):

Tty using :

```
for($i = 0 ; $i< sizeof($months) ; $i++){
     echo "'".$months[$i]."'";
     if($i != (sizeof($months)-1))
       echo ", ";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$my_array = array('October', 'NOvember');
echo "'" . implode("', '", $my_array) . "'";
```